# Script to proxy just one website with the folder structure?

Tags: .htaccess, proxy

I'm looking for a proxy script (or possibly some .htaccess voodoo**) that allows just one domain to be proxied, while keeping the folder structure intact. Ideally I would also give it a wildcard DNS and it would do subdomains too, but that's not necessary because I can also just set up the proxy a few times (once for each subdomain).

So say the original site is someawesomesite.com. And my proxy is at myawesomeproxy.com. I want to be able to go to myawesomeproxy.com/thisawesomedocument.html and see the same as I would when I would go to someawesomesite.com/thisawesomedocument.html.

Also, my hoster only has PHP, no CGI or ASP etc. so it would need to be in PHP (or as I said before if you guys could cook up some .htaccess voodoo, that would be awesome too!)

Basically [what they pulled off over here](http://tpb.piratenpartij.nl/) but with another site than The Pirate Bay...

** I'm not the server owner (shared hosting), so I can't install Apache plugins or edit configs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `P`(proxy flag). Remember for this to work `mod_proxy` should be enabled. 
*Assuming that the directory structure are the same & `mod_proxy` is enabled by your shared hosting*. **Try** this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?someawesomesite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myawesomeproxy.com/$1 [P,L]
```

Comment: My host doesn't have mod_proxy... (When I view phpinfo.php and do a search for 'mod_proxy', it turns up nothing. That would mean my host doesn't have mod_proxy, right?)

Comment: @user1062698 Yup you are right. just look under this section `Configuration
apache2handler`: subsection: `Loaded Modules`.